# WP redirect rule doesn't work

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to redirect the page `http://www.example.org/newsletter/unsubscribe.html` to `http://www.example.org/newsletter/unsubscribe`.

I have tried the following:

```
add_rewrite_rule('newsletter/unsubscribe.html$', 'newsletter/unsubscribe', 'top');
```

If I `var_dump` the **global** `wp_rewrite` i see the following rule added:

```
  ...
  public 'non_wp_rules' => 
    array (size=1)
      'newsletter/unsubscribe.html$' => string 'newsletter/unsubscribe' (length=20)
  ...
```

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: Do you want to perform a redirection or rewrite the URL? They are different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: that's not how rewrite rules work. You can see how they work in [the examples section of the codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule#Example).

It sounds like what you're trying to do is setup a redirect. I would suggest using [a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/) to do that.

Comment: Thanks, got it working now with `add_rewrite_rule('newsletter/unsubscribe.html$', 'index.php?page_id=234300', 'top');`